# How to combine two middle-grey images and keep the same value?

Tags: compositing-nodes

(i have answered myself, problem solved)

If two middle-grey (0.5 value) images are used and combined in Overlay mode the image will get darker. How can i keep the same value and add the details of both textures?

Here is the ambiant occlusion map with a middle-grey:

[image]

And here i add another texture in overlay with a middle-grey this can be a bent map for the lighting or a curvature map, as you can see the image becomes darker and it becomes very dark if i increase the factor:

[image]

Comment: instead of editing the question and marking it as problem solved, mark your own answer as accepted.

Comment: I must wait one more day to be able to click it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two textures with a middle-grey and keep the same value connect your previous image to an overlay node and the new in the second slot.

Because Blender uses sRGB and not a Linear color management you need to correct the gamma by connecting it to a gamma node in the image slot and for the second slot connect a math Divide node with 1 on top et 2.2.

[image]

Comment: You can prevent the sRBG transform and keep your values linear by saving to OpenEXR. If you choose to use a display referred format then use the Non-Color Data option.